# LogoutManager Logout doesn't work, and ShareDialog doesn't pop up

Tags: android, facebook

I was trying to upload an image in the Facebook using the code below, however, the photo will be uploaded but it doesn't give me the right to type the caption. In other words, the ShareDialog isn't popping out.

Also, about the Logout, I created a custom Logout button. In the onClick listener I added `LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()` but it doesn't log me out in the facebook.

```
private void publishImage() {
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), img2[res2]);
    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE +
            "://" + getResources().getResourcePackageName(img2[res2])
            + '/' + getResources().getResourceTypeName(img2[res2]) + '/' + getResources().getResourceEntryName(img2[res2]));
    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setImageUrl(imageUri)
            .build();
    ShareApi.share(linkContent, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
            thanktv.setText("Thank you " + et1.getText() + "!");
            thank.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.v("FACEBOOK_TEST", "share api cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Log.v("FACEBOOK_TEST", "share api error " + e);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using

Comment: Try getting the active session and logging out, and later make the session null

Comment: What do you mean by that? How do I do that?